# ktor dependency in commonMain of Android Studio multiplatform project unresolved in IDE but code runs

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, gradle-dependencies, source-sets

I have an issue with the Android Studio IDE when using the ktor dependency for the commonMain sourceset with kotlin multiplatform. The problem is that the IDE does not recognize this dependency, but the program compiles and runs fine. Furthermore, in the androidMain sourceset the dependency is recognized. I have seen other questions on similar problems, but I have not seen anyone with this problem where the program compiles and runs.

Gradle dependencies

The following is in the build.gradle.kts in the shared folder of the project.

```
kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.5.1")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.5.1")
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

where the dots represent dependencies for other sourcesets, e.g. iosMain which is empty.

In the commonMain code, I have a class KtorTest:

```
package com.example.myapplication222.shared

import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*

class KtorTest {
    val client: HttpClient = HttpClient(CIO)

    suspend fun get(): String {
        val res: String = client.get("http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=113.17&lat=23.09&product=astro&output=json")
        return res
    }
}
```

Main Activity

In the main activity I import and use the KtorTest class to perform a get request.

```
package com.example.myapplication222.androidApp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.myapplication222.shared.KtorTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var response = ""

        val c = GlobalScope.launch {
            response = get()
        }

        c.invokeOnCompletion { 
            println("***RESPONSE***");
            println(response) }
    }

    suspend fun get(): String {
        val a = KtorTest()
        return a.get()
    }
}
```

Result

The program builds and runs and prints out the following.

```
I/System.out: ***RESPONSE***
    {
        "product" : "astro" ,
        "init" : "2021021700" ,
        "dataseries" : [
        {
            "timepoint" : 3,
            "cloudcover" : 4,
I/System.out:       "seeing" : 6,
            "transparency" : 2,
            "lifted_index" : 15,
            "rh2m" : 5,
            "wind10m" : {
                "direction" : "NE",
                "speed" : 3
            },
            "temp2m" : 20,
            "prec_type" : "none"
        },
    ...
}

where the response is cut short for brevity
```

Screenshot of Android Studio:

The first screenshot is of KtorTest presented above.

[KtorTest in commonMain of shared code in Android Studio kotlin multiplatform project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXm8s.png)

The second screenshot is of the class KtorTest2, which is exactly the same as KtorTest above except that it is located in the androidMain folder of the shared folder in the multiplatform project.

[KtorTest2 in androidMain of shared code in Android Studio kotlin multiplatform project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mouQ5.png)

In these images you can see that the IDE complains about ktor in commonMain, but not in androidMain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating kotlin-gradle-plugin to 1.4.31 in build.gradle.kts of the kotlin multiplatform project fixed this issue

See the following answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913665/14635103

Answer (score 1):

You only need to include `io.ktor:ktor-client-core` in `commonMain` and actual HTTP engine implementation in desired target. If you want to use CIO engine in android, just include `io.ktor:ktor-client-cio` in `androidMain`. Ktor will automatically select available HTTP client available for the platform. You can update the `KtorTest` class like so (note the absence of engine specification):

```
class KtorTest {
    val client: HttpClient = HttpClient
}
```

Comment: I see, but this did not help with the syntax highlighting. I think there is something wrong with my gradle

Comment: Try to invalidate cache/restart the ide.

Comment: Invalidating the cache and restarting did not help. What is interesting is that this is not an issue when I open the client-mpp project of the following sample code in android studio https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples